# django-image-cropping not working in admin interface

Tags: python, django, image

I'm using [django-image-cropping](https://github.com/jonasundderwolf/django-image-cropping) in my django project and I followed the official guidelines but still I'm not getting the desired result.
Here the snippet of my project files.

I already added `easy_thumbnails` and `image_cropping` to my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

**settings.py**

```
from easy_thumbnails.conf import Settings as thumbnail_settings
THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS = (
    'image_cropping.thumbnail_processors.crop_corners',
) + thumbnail_settings.THUMBNAIL_PROCESSORS
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from image_cropping import ImageRatioField    
class UserData(models.Model):
        fullname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        user = models.CharField(max_length=70, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename,blank=False, null=False)
        cropping = ImageRatioField('image', '180x180')
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from image_cropping import ImageCroppingMixin
class UserDataModelAdmin(ImageCroppingMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    # filter_horizontal=['image']
    pass

admin.site.register(UserData, UserDataModelAdmin)
```

As per the official guidelines its enough to see the enhanced selection area in the admin panel, but I'm not getting it. Instead I'm getting this.
[image]

> No option for cropping.

Please help me to sort this out.

Comment: You could solve this problem? Thank you...

Comment: there's no field for the cropping `ImageRatioField` ? cause those 3 look right. The one where you crop would be the field for the cropping property

Comment: Issue is still occurring 7 years later 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this tool [django-imagekit-cropper](https://github.com/ninapavlich/django-imagekit-cropper), it has nice features and very good documentation. you need to create a form.py file and need to mention this

```
from django import forms
    from imagekit_cropper.widgets import ImageCropWidget    
    from .models import UserData


    class ImageAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
        square_150_crop = forms.CharField(widget=ImageCropWidget(properties=Image.square_150_crop_properties, help_text=Image.help['square_150_crop']))

        class Meta:
            model = UserData
```

Answer (score 1):

Though this isn't covered in the documentation, I found that I needed to add the `cropping` attribute from my model to my custom `UserAdmin` fieldsets:

```
fieldsets = (
    (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
    ('Personal info', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'gender',
        'phone', 'address', 'postal_code', 'city', 'student', 'university',
        'newsletter', 'birthday', 'avatar', 'cropping')}),
```

Where my `image` attribute is alternatively names `avatar`.